# pmap hangs on OOM process

Tags: bash, shell-script, out-of-memory

I did attempt a search, but there doesn't appear to be much out there on pmap so here goes.

I have a script that works with WebLogic instances to gather data on them which we can send to our Devs for troubleshooting. Included in the data-collection is a pmap on the PID of the specified instance, but when the instance is experiencing stuck threads, large OC, or is in a failed state, the pmap hangs.

Due to the fact that timeout is not installed on the Servers we work with (and cannot be) I've attempted to write a condition to let the pmap process run for no longer than 45 seconds and kill it if it does, but it doesn't seem to be working as the pmap still hangs on affected instances.

Here's the code:

```
echo "Running pmap for a maximum of 45 seconds..."
pmap -x $1 > /tmp/pmapdump.txt &
pmapPID=$!
sleep 10
 pmapRunning=$(pgrep -fl "${pmapPID}" |head -1 |awk '{print $1}')
if [ "${pmapRunning}" != "" ]; then
  sleep 30
  echo "The pmap appears to be stuck. This typically happens if the instance is in a failed state or has stuck threads."
  echo "Killing the pmap and moving on with the rest of the script..."
  kill -9 "${pmapPID}"
else
  :
fi
```

This is called by the main script and does appear to execute correctly, except for NOT killing the process and hanging like it did before I decided to create this script.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated as I'm starting to pull my hair out over this.